# Display specific area of map using MapKit iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, ipod

I am very new to Mapkit IOS. I am creating application that should display only specific region like Germany on map and remaining area should become black as seen in the picture attached.

[Expecting Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcAia.jpg)

**This is the code which I did as of now:**

**ViewController.h**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
MKMapView *mapview;

}

- (IBAction)setMap:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapview;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize mapview = _mapview;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a       nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)setMap:(id)sender {

switch (((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        _mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;

        break;
    case 1:
        _mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
        break;
    case 2:
        _mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
        break;

    default:
        break;
  }

}
@end
```

Comment: Upload code how did you achieve this.

Comment: Sachin Please Check I uploaded the code.

Comment: I think you didn't set the constraints properly. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html follow the tutorial.

Comment: I set the Constraints it was working fine...The challenge is I need to display specific region on map like India remaining area should become black this is my goal. Can you please help me how to start...https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcAia.jpg like this

Comment: You need to identify the country boundaries and draw a UIBeizerPath and colour it with black.